# Coming from Spanish, where do I start learning English?

Tags: learning-methods, online-learning, spanish

Is there any manual or website that you recommend for starting to learn English?

Honestly, with my mother tongue (Spanish) I have forgotten and sometimes left without understanding, some concepts that are now used in English. For this reason I look for something from the most basic to the most advanced.

Some have recommended I start without worrying about grammar and the truth is that something, very basic, I understand, but not like to read on the run; and I need to get to that point because I have important manuals to study.

I will read your fact-based advice.

Answer (score 0):

To build up solid foundations for your learning journey, I recommend you the *Books4Languages* website where you can find free textbooks for English grammar and vocabulary from beginner A1 to upper-intermediate B2 level as well as some exercises to practice what you have learned. Moreover, the books for the A1 and A2 levels are offered also in Spanish. In addition to this, I also suggest you try *Memrise* (you can find both the website and app version) through which you can dive deeper into the English language thanks to its interactive lessons which also feature real-life situations.

Comment: Ok, folks. In English, "recommend" cannot take a object pronoun like that. It can take this: **I recommend you start with Books4Languages website**. And: I recommended you for the job. But not: I recommend you the site.